# How to set specific color to some bars in a plotly bar graph?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

I'm trying to set different colors for some bars in a plotly express bar graph:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['2020/01', '2020/02', '2020/03', '2020/04',  
         '2020/05', '2020/07', '2020/08'],  
        'Value':[34,56,66,78,99,55,22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

color_discrete_sequence = ['#ec7c34']*len(df)
color_discrete_sequence[5] = '#609cd4'
fig=px.bar(df,x='Name',y='Value',color_discrete_sequence=color_discrete_sequence)
fig.show()
```

My expectations were that one (the sixth one) bar had a different color, however I got this result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because `color` in `px.bar` is used to name a category to illustrate traits or dimensions of a dataset using a colorscale. Or  in you your case, rather a color *cycle* since you're dealing with a categorical / discrete case. `color_discrete_sequence` is then used to specify which color sequence to follow. One way to achieve your goal using your setup here, is to simply define a string variable with unique values, for example like `df['category'] [str(i) for i in df.index]`, and then use:

```
fig=px.bar(df,x='Name',y='Value',
           color = 'category',
           color_discrete_sequence=color_discrete_sequence,
           )
```

#### Plot:

[image]

If `df['category']` is a numerical value, `color_discrete_sequence` will be ignored, and a default continuous sequence will be applied:

[image]

If anything else is unclear, don't hesitate to let me know.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['2020/01', '2020/02', '2020/03', '2020/04',  
         '2020/05', '2020/07', '2020/08'],  
        'Value':[34,56,66,78,99,55,22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['category'] = [str(i) for i in df.index]
# df['category'] = df.index

color_discrete_sequence = ['#ec7c34']*len(df)
color_discrete_sequence[5] = '#609cd4'
fig=px.bar(df,x='Name',y='Value',
           color = 'category',
           color_discrete_sequence=color_discrete_sequence,
           )
fig.show()
```

Comment: Tks, vestland. One question: why (I tried it) it doesn't work if I set color = 'Name'? It is a string field, after all.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: The same of the picture I posted in the question.

Comment: Ups, sorry. My mistake, it works. Tks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer. And perhaps even consider an upvote if it was useful to you.

Comment: How can I do both?

Comment: You'll find an up-arrow and a checkmark next to the score that currently says `0`.